# Flutter/Android: Twilio Programmable Video is causing app & system performance to degrade after subsequent calls

Tags: android, flutter, twilio, android-camera2, twilio-programmable-voice

I've configured Twilio Programmable Video using this package: https://gitlab.com/twilio-flutter/programmable-video/

But I've realized it is causing the app & system performance to degrade.
Then after some investigation, I found that EGLRenderer is still running after disconnect/dispose the room.

I've seen logs like this: `EglRenderer: Duration: 4006 ms. Frames received: 0. Dropped: 0. Rendered: 0. Render fps: .0. Average render time: NA. Average swapBuffer time: NA.`  printing in logcat and logs comes infinitely (with interval of around 1s) and also multiplies the rate with the times I disconnected from the room.

Tried to resolve by:

- By changing the the `dispose` method of the `ParticipantView` class in the native side of the Android to:

```kotlin
override fun dispose() {
   debug("dispose => Disposing ParticipantView")
   videoTrack.removeSink(videoView)
   videoView.release()
}
```

But this didn't help much but changing the previous logs print
from:

```
EglRenderer: Duration: 4006 ms. Frames received: 0. Dropped: 0. Rendered: 0. Render fps: .0. Average render time: NA. Average swapBuffer time: NA.
```

to: this

```
E/BufferQueueProducer(16848): [SurfaceTexture-0-16848-1](id:41d000000005,api:1,p:1097,c:16848) dequeueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
```

The performance degradation issue still happens now I see `E/BufferQueueProducer` logs instead of `EglRenderer` logs.

Thanks.